# Scala diverging implicit expansion for cats.effect.Timer when using monix TaskApp

Tags: scala, implicit, monix

CE 2.x. Monix 3.4. Line 1 compiles, line 2 gives a compilation error:

diverging implicit expansion for type cats.kernel.Order[A]
starting with method catsKernelOrderForFunction0 in object Eq
Stream.sleep_(5.seconds).compile.drain.as(ExitCode.Success) // 2

```scala
import cats.effect.{ExitCode, Timer}
import fs2.Stream
import monix.eval.{Task, TaskApp}
import scala.concurrent.duration.DurationInt


object ImplicitsFreeze extends TaskApp {

  def run(args: List[String]): Task[ExitCode] = {
    Stream.sleep_(5.seconds)(implicitly[Timer[Task]]).compile.drain.as(ExitCode.Success)  // 1
//    Stream.sleep_(5.seconds).compile.drain.as(ExitCode.Success) // 2
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding annotation of the effect type solves the issue

```scala
Stream.sleep_[Task](5.seconds).compile.drain.as(ExitCode.Success) // 2
```